# Facebook Graph API: How do I get a user's (or own) link-likes (i.e. 'user likes a link')?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

By link-like I mean a generic page on the Web (link) that a user likes using a Facebook button (i.e. NOT a Facebook standard page).

The Graph API method /user/feed does not return link-likes.

The Graph API method /user/likes only returns Facebook page likes, but not link-likes.

Do you know of any ways that I could get to link-likes?

Answer (score 0):

When you get this kind of entry you get and id something like:

```
"id": "1392236262_349397875123264"
```

The first part of id is user id, the second is the liked link id. You can get an information about it by running other Facebook Graph API call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/349397875123264
```

This way you will get all information about this link.

Answer (score 0):

You can get list of liked urls using fql:

```
SELECT url FROM url_like WHERE user_id = me()
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/url_like/